# How to check if object is before or after the DOM with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

For example, you have 2 div's.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

How would I check if `$("#div1")` is before `$("#div2")` in the DOM? I have no idea what to try and can not find anything about it on the web. So all suggestions and idea's would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the index of both div in collection of div element. the one which is higher is after the other element:

```
if($('div').index($('#div2')) > $('div').index($('#div1'))){
   //div 2 is after div1
}
```